# что означают Force Checkout and Smart Checkout, git

Tags: git, phpstorm

Скажите, пож-ста, что означают Force Checkout and Smart Checkout?

В чем их принципальное отличие?

И почему у меня при смене веток инфа из старой ветки попадает в новую ветку? Так должно быть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Если у вас при переключении веток есть незакоммиченные изменения, то возникает вопрос что с ними делать. Тут 2 варианта:

1. Можно их просто удалить - это `force checkout`.
2. Можно их сохранить во временное хранилище, переключиться на ветку и восстановить из временного хранилища.

У вас как раз таки второй вариант случается. Тут надо быть аккуратным. Если ветки сильно отличаются, то восстановление из хранилища вызовет конфликты и вам придётся их мержить в ветку на которую вы переключились.

Comment: Спасибо, а если я не хочу коммитить, но хочу сохранить свои данные... перед переключением веток, и данные из старой ветки не хочу мерджить в новую ветку.

Comment: Если ветки сильно отличаются, то восстановление из хранилища вызовет конфликты и вам придётся их мержить в ветку на которую вы переключились.- Да это есть, и я расстраиваюсь, так как мне не нужно.... Как вы решаете этот вопрос, обычно...

Comment: @Rabin, ну, в гите есть возможность вручную сохранить изменения во временное хранилище. После этого их можно достать также вручную на любой ветке. Вроде как можно это и через UI сделать. Попробуйте официальную доку: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/shelving-and-unshelving-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

Ты работаешь в ветке **old-branch**.

У тебя есть изменения, которые ты ещё не закоммитил.
Ты решил переключиться на ветку **new-branch**.

**Force Checkout** - принудительное переключение ветки. 
Твои изменения будут перезаписаны данными из new-branch и изменения будут утеряны.

**Smart Checkout** - при переключении незакомиченные изменения будут помещены в Shelve,
потом будет загружена новая ветка,
затем изменения из Shelve будут загружены,
если появятся конфликты во время этого процесса, то будет предложено их решить.